# Ma Nishtana: Why does it say "On other nights we don't dip even once?"

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

Rav CF ben DanF *omeir* ...

*Mah Nishtanah* says that on all other nights of the year, we don't dip even once. My son says, "That's not quite true. On Shabbat (and some people do it at each meal), people dip the bread in salt. On Rosh Hashanna, people dip bread and an apple in honey. So, why does (the current version vs. Mishnah version) say that we don't dip at all?"

Comment: I see you just edited your q,bevause the mishna has diff girsos

Comment: i think it means that there is no chiyuv to dip. As far as the "chiyuv" to dip bread in salt - see gemara berachot - this chiyuv is only if the bread does not have a good taste already, meaning the chiyuv has nothing to do with the act of dipping rather the outcome...NOTE There is still a chiyuv according to kabbalah to dip bread in salt regardless of the taste

Comment: @IbberChochem There are different versions about whether dipping the bread is a *chiyuv* or not. In terms of the *Ma Nishtana* question, I don't believe that even in the Mishnah's version, there was any chiyuv to dip vegetables (or whatever) into something either. Essentially, the question is comparing two *minhagim*.

Comment: @Ibber Pesachim 116a poses our reading as a response to a proposed text "for on all nights we are not obligated to dip even once, but tonight we are obligated to dip twice." The problem is that we're not obligated to dip twice on the Seder night; Karpas is only so the kids will ask, and so it can be skipped if something else is used to get them to ask, according to the basic obligation. As DanF correctly stated, it seems to be just minhag whether bread must be dipped in salt or not, and it's also minhag to dip apples in honey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ritva say this means we don’t normally dip before the meal i.e. by karpas which is way before the actual meal, Shulchan Orech. [image: source]

Comment: +1. Please link in the source when you can. I guess he counts *hamotzi* as part of the meal even though you haven't eaten anything, yet.

Comment: See added picture

Comment: Thanks, again. What is this *Hagaddah* called? Available in a good Judaica / Seforim store, or out of print?

Comment: http://zbermanbooks.com/הגדת-הראשונים-והאחרונים (also in stores)